# React MUI Select with react-form-hook not updating select label

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am trying to make a MUI Select that also uses React Form Hook. Currently i'm able to create the select component but it won't update the label on value changes.

Below is the snippet of my select component and also the output.

```js
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="designTypeId"
  render={({ field }) => {
    return (
      <Select
        {...register('designTypeId', {
          required: 'This field is required'
        })}
        className="w-full"
        displayEmpty
        error={!!errors.designTypeId}
        label="Design Type"
        labelId="designTypeId-label"
        startAdornment={
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            <Email />
          </InputAdornment>
        }
        value={''}>
        <MenuItem disabled value="">
          Select a design type
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={40}>Thirty</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    );
  }}
/>
```

[image]

When i remove `value={''}` the select component, it able to update the label on change value. But it not displaying the placeholder or default selected option (Select a design type)

```js
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="designTypeId"
  render={({ field }) => {
    return (
      <Select
        {...register('designTypeId', {
          required: 'This field is required'
        })}
        className="w-full"
        displayEmpty
        error={!!errors.designTypeId}
        label="Design Type"
        labelId="designTypeId-label"
        startAdornment={
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            <Email />
          </InputAdornment>
        }>
        <MenuItem disabled value="">
          Select a design type
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={40}>Thirty</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    );
  }}
/>
```

[image]
[image]

Is there any workaround to make this select component can show the default selected option / placeholder and also update the label on change value?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "defaultValue" instead of "value". It should select your default value when nothing is selected, and change to the correct selection if needed.